# Set permission for Role to none

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, user-roles

How do you set the permission for a role to nothing? When I try to set permission to `[]`, it doesn't work for me.

I wanna do something like this

```
     role.edit({
                data: {
                    name:"noRights", 
                    permissions:[none], //No permissions to Write Messages, read...
                    color:"GRAY",
                }, reason:"Cuz I want"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `permissions` to an empty array will deny all the role permissions.
Your code is not working because you are defining the data in an existing Object.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=edit), data is an Object itself, passed as the first parameter.

---

```js
role.edit({
    name: "noRights",
    permissions: [],
    color: "GRAY"
}, "Cuz I want");
```